# Can I be just a Muslim rather than being a tableeqi or sunni

Tags: hadith, sunnah

Assalamu alaikum brother, as you are no there are number firaqas in Islam now like tableeqi Sunni , devbandi etc. And I have also heard a Hadith of prophet Muhammad s.w.a.w. that there will be about 73 firqas in Islam but followers of any one jamat will go into the jannat. My question is is if I I stay out of these things and just follow the Islam buy Quran and follow the footsteps of prophet Mohammed s.w.a.w ( e.g: giving dawat to Muslim brothers but not being strictly be called as tableeqi and not following their rules strictly) .
Can I still go to jannat.

Comment: If your question is are tableeghi right or wrong? Than this is off-topic (we are not here to discuss which view of Islam is right or wrong). If your question is do I have a chance to go to jannah, if I followed the qur'an and sunnah as good as I can, than I must ask why not?

Comment: No not at all asking weather a particular jamaat is right or wrong. All I want to ask is if I don't call myself strictly as a tableeqi or Sunni or devbandi etc , and just follow the Quran and prophet Muhammad peace be upon him can I still go to Jennat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If one reads the Mushaf al shareef and look at all the verses which mention the word "Muslim" it ALWAYS coupled with "Allah" . In other words whenever Allah is mentioned in the Mushaf al shareef the word Muslim or Muslims is associated with Allah. So being a Muslim has to do with the strict belief in God / Allah the one without any partners or anything like him. So based on the Al Mushaf the definition of a Muslim is one that who believes in the One Allah, the day of Judgement and does good ( #amala Sali7an).

So if one say the first part of the Shahadda.... La illaha illa Allah he or she becomes a Muslim. The second part of the Shahadda is for the belief in the Messenger Mohamed (PBU).

There is only one religion in the Mushaf and no plural religions.... all others are called "Millah" like the Christians and the Jews those are Millah and not religions.

Sunni, Shia and others are simply different ways to worship Allah

Those ideas and more are from Dr. Mohamed Shahroor

Salam

Comment: Wrong Islam is belief in Allah and His prophet(s) . And your claim about Millah requires some elaboration and evidences supporting your claims.

Comment: Millah is also used in a positive sense for Ibrahim. Millata Ibrahim hanifan.